# Setting android theme

Tags: android, colors, styles, themes

I would like to know why is it happen. I set different accent colors in two styles. When i apply it into the login activity, the accent color do not change into the colorPrimary and still is the colorAccent. So what can i do to apply different accent color? and why it happens? Thank you.

This is the Style code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

This is the Manifest code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignupActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <actvity></actvity>
```

Comment: i am using the scrollview in the layout of the log inactivity. Dose it relate or lead to the problem?